# 2d unity game asking permissions which i didn't mentioned in my code

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-permissions

I'm a beginner at 2D Unity game development and this is my first game. In this game In the AndroidManifest file the permissions mentioned are :

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

but when I generated an apk and tried it in my android, it asks some wired permissions, like the one shown in the pictures below :

I have not specified anything related to this in my code, but why am I getting this, anyone has any clue how to solve this issue? , thanks for your time.

**updating question**

in my app, I found out these permissions
but I didn't mention these and have not used any plugins and imported any assets, packages can anyone tell what are these permissions and why are they here?

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.xiaomi.sdk.permission.PAYMENT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.xiaomi.permission.AUTH_SERVICE" />
```

[image][image]

Comment: Are you using any plugin? Because their AndroidManifest will be merged with your one.

Comment: no i'm not using any plugins @JeanLuc

Comment: You're not using any unity plugins at all?  Nothing from their 2d platformer kit, or anything imported from the package manager?  Can you also specify the version of Unity you are using?

Comment: yes i'm not using any plugins and the current version of my unity is 2018.2.5f1

Comment: question updated guys !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after struggling for a day , finally i found the reason , unity itself adding a package that is **xiaomi mi game center** by default to android unity apps , which requires these permissions after removing that in the build settings the problem solved for me.

hope my answer helps someone !

[image]